# Couldn't we have more simple redirect_to parameter?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

While learning Rails, I found this example in the Sam Ruby's book:

**app/controllers/line_items_controller.rb**

```
def create
        @cart = current_cart
        product = Product.find(params[:product_id])
        @line_item = @cart.line_items.build
        @line_item.product = product

        respond_to do |format|
          if @line_item.save
            # this following line is strange for me 
            format.html { redirect_to(@line_item.cart, :notice => 'Line item was successfully created.') }
            format.xml  { render :xml => @line_item, :status => :created, :location => @line_item }
          else
            format.html { render :action => "new" }
            format.xml  { render :xml => @line_item.errors,
              :status => :unprocessable_entity }
          end
        end
  end
```

Why isn't the section with `redirect_to(@line_item.cart,...)` merely replaced by `redirect_to(@cart,...)` ?

Indeed, @cart is an accessible instance variable.

Are we forced to use `@line_item` to retrieve cart in this example ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there some sort of nested route involved in this example?
You could simply do a `redirect_to @cart` the example should still work.

Try it out. But it should work from my understanding. Maybe the author wanted to be a little bit more expressive in the whose cart he redirects to.

Comment: No there is no nested route involved in this example. The author wrote: "Once the line item is created, we want to redirect you to the cart instead of back to the line item itself. Since the line object knows how to find the cart object, all we need to do is add .cart to the method call". So, with a long precision like this, I wondered if this way of doing is THE way :).

Comment: No this is not the only way. Actually the route helper will just look at the object that is passed (@cart) and match it against it's routes. So if the route file has a `resources :cart` it will match it to the show_cart path. No idea why the author decided to write it this way.

Comment: I totally agree with you, I don't understand its goal with this precision. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

These are the times where we have to assume that the author is trying to convey,

**"after saving this line_item, goto the cart which HAS THIS line_item"** => readability.

There are two things that a good code should offer, no matter what,

1. READABILITY.
2. ROOM FOR FUTURE MODIFICATION.

I realized their necessity out of experience, reality. (Not from a book)

OPTIMIZATION can be considered after getting the right OUTPUT.

Correct me if Im wrong.